# [OpenFL][HTML5 Target] BlendMode not working

Tags: html, flash, haxe, blending, openfl

I'm adding a Sprite with a bitmap inside to the stage, than i change blendMode to SCREEN.
Nothing happens on HTML5 targets while on flash everything works fine...
OPENFL Wiki says "Available on all platforms" (link)

Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code im using:

```
var sp:Sprite = new Sprite();
sp.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, 1);
sp.graphics.drawCircle(200, 200, 100);
sp.graphics.endFill();
addChild(sp);

var bmd:BitmapData = Assets.getBitmapData("img/1.jpg");
var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
b.blendMode = BlendMode.SCREEN;

addChild(b);
```

Imporets are:

```
import openfl.Assets;
import openfl.display.BitmapData;
import openfl.display.Bitmap;
import openfl.display.BlendMode;
import openfl.display.Sprite;
```

Flash Target:

[image: Flash export print screen]

HTML5 Target:

[image: HTML5 export print screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, HTML5 canvas doesn't have `BlendMode` support, HTML5 webGL does. Try compiling it with `lime test html5 -Dwebgl`

[image]